# Copying empty arrays: difference between Mono and .Net Core

Tags: .net, arrays, f#, mono, .net-core

I have some .Net code whose tests were all passing on Mono, but once I ran it on .Net Core, several tests failed. I eventually tracked the failing tests down to their root cause, and discovered something rather curious, which I'd like to ask about here where more experienced .Net coders can help me.

Essentially, the root cause of the failure was that I was copying an empty array of type A into a destination array of type B. (I'll refrain from explaining *why* I was copying an empty array, so that you don't have to wade through page after page of code. It keeps the code simpler; most of the time the source array was of type B, but sometimes the creation code would create an empty array of type A). Mono said "Oh, the array is empty, so I won't throw a type error", and the copy was successful. But when I ran the tests on .Net Core, copying an empty array of type A into a destination array of type B threw a `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException` with the message:

> Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.

Here's some code so that I can show you what I mean in code rather than in English. (In F# code, specifically, since that's the language I was working with when I came across this interesting difference between Mono and .Net Core).

```
let someStrs : string[] = [|"a"; "b"; "c"|]
let someInts : int[] = Array.zeroCreate 3
someStrs.CopyTo(someInts, 0)
```

For anyone who doesn't read F# very well, the first line creates an array of three strings, as you could probably figure out. (F# uses `[|` and `|]` to declare arrays, because the `[` and `]` brackets have the meaning of defining a singly-linked list.) The second line creates an array of three ints, initialized to their default value. For ints that's 0, so this creates the array `[|0; 0; 0|]`, but if I was saying `let someStrs : string[] = Array.zeroCreate 3` then the resulting array would be `[|null; null; null|]`.

That code will, naturally, fail: you can't copy an array of strings into an array of integers. And it does fail, both on Mono and on .Net Core. But now look at this:

```
let someStrs : string[] = [||]
let someInts : int[] = Array.zeroCreate 3
someStrs.CopyTo(someInts, 0)
```

Same code as before, only this time I've defined `someStrs` as an **empty array**, an array of length 0. It still has the type `string[]`, so will copying it to an array of type `int[]` be a type error, or not? Well, it turns out that this code **fails on .Net Core**, but **works on Mono**.

Note: I do not currently have a Windows machine available to me to test on, so I don't know how this would behave on .Net Framework (let's say version 4.7.1, since I'm running on Mono 5.10 which [supports .Net 4.7.1](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.10.0/) according to their release notes. But I compiled against the `net461` target, so perhaps .Net Framework 4.6.1 would be a better choice to test against).

So my question is, **which behavior is correct?** Should copying a zero-length array have thrown a type error on Mono, and this is a bug I should report on Mono? Or is .Net Core's implementation in error, and the fact that the source array is of length 0 is what should have "won", and no type error should have been thrown? I've never come across a reference to this particular situation in any of the .Net/C#/F# documentation I've seen, so I don't know what the .Net CLR spec says should happen in this case.

Comment: Mono is buggy, for sure.

Comment: I just tried it with .Net 4.6.1 and got the same type exception. IMO, the exception is the correct behavior.

Comment: @glenebob - Thanks, good to know. I've updated my code to avoid the situation, so the empty arrays of type A are never copied to type B. This was one of the weirder Mono bugs I've personally encountered.

Comment: Seems to me as a bug. If you can see at array's implementation on mono [Array.Copy](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/8f926ed4648d0e175485665675a4b415e3652e14/mcs/class/corlib/System/Array.cs#L583) you can see that it tries to check for type mismatch. But .NET core relies on the system to copy the array. as you can find out here [.NET Core Array.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Array.cs)